# SQL query group by with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Couldn't think of a better title for this question the time being, but here's a sample of the data set I'm working with:

```
Token                                   Buyer            Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------
F3D4A490-03C9-450E-873B-3B70E68FA65B    Company B        1.50
F3D4A490-03C9-450E-873B-3B70E68FA65B    Company C        0.99
A85677D8-C5A9-4766-8628-AADD769240C2    Company A        3.14
A85677D8-C5A9-4766-8628-AADD769240C2    Company B        2.44
FB72BEE1-194C-48D3-8EC1-669776E8924C    Company C        2.01
E9FFACBF-F9B1-4278-B49D-42E605F21D28    Company B        1.25
```

I need to get a list of Token values that match one of the following two conditions:

- There is only one of that particular token present in the data set.
- There are more than one of that particular token, but none of the "Buyer" values are "Company A".

In this case, my desired result set would contain the following:

```
F3D4A490-03C9-450E-873B-3B70E68FA65B
FB72BEE1-194C-48D3-8EC1-669776E8924C 
E9FFACBF-F9B1-4278-B49D-42E605F21D28
```

Getting a list based on having a single token is easy enough. I can do a GROUP BY with a HAVING COUNT(*) = 1. It's the second condition that's giving me some trouble.

Performance is not a consideration for this solution, it's a one-off query that I'll be running.

Comment: As it's ad-hoc, just write 2 queries and UNION them together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Token
FROM   TableName
GROUP BY Token
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT Token
FROM   TableName
WHERE  Token NOT IN
       (
           SELECT Token
           FROM   TableName
           WHERE  Buyer = 'Company A'
       )
GROUP BY Token
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```